# Speeding up nested evaluations (Isabelle/HOL)

Tags: performance, functional-programming, terminate, isabelle

I have an Isabelle/HOL definition looks like

```
definition "f1 args = filter g (f0 args)",
```

where f0 returns a list (this detail is not particularly important, though).

Now, if I try to compute

```
value "f1 args0",
```

for a specific value of args0, this is slower than

```
value "f0 args0" 
definition "f0args0 = <content pasted from the results obtained above>"
value "filter g f0args0"
```

When I have a big number of nested definitions (say f(n+1) whose definitions depend on f(n), f(n-1), ..., f0), 
this problem becomes unbearable: if I try a computation involving f(n+1), it will never terminate,
while if I manually split computations as above, feeding the output of f(j) to f(j+1) by copy and paste, it will.

However, this is unbearable work for even moderately large n.

Is there something I can do about that? Or is that a fundamental limitation of functional programming?
(I'm saying that because by the copy/paste above I am formally introducing side effects, I think)

Thanks!

Comment: Neither of the two should, in principle, be faster than the other. If anything, the first version should actually be faster. Without seeing the actual code, I cannot say any more. If it really never terminates, there might be some other effect playing into this (some problem with code equations perhaps).